# How can I fetch the activity_message value if my conditions are verified:

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Sample data:

```py
user_id = 1
project_id = 2
a = [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
    },
    "data": {
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "activity_message": "Success 1",
        "activity_created_on": {
            "$date": "2023-02-28T12:30:55.652Z"
        }
    }
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
    },
    "data": {
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "activity_message": "Success 2",
        "activity_created_on": {
            "$date": "2023-02-28T12:36:55.652Z"
        }
    }
}]
```

I tried in this way: To sort the messages based on `activity_created_on` key to get last entry first.

```py
def tags(a):
    tags = set()
    for item in a:
       if item.get('data'):
           if all([item["data"]["user_id"]==user_id, item["data"]["project_id"]==project_id]):
            q.r  =  item["data"]["activity_message"]item["data"]["activity_created_on"]["$date"]
            tags.add(q,r)
    return tags
print(tags(a))
```

I am trying to get the output as last come first serve based on `activity_created_on` key.

Expected output:

```
Success 2
Success 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easy implementation, just use `list` instead `set`. Just create a list of objects which includes `activity_message` and `activity_created_on.$date`, so it can be reverse-sorted by that date. Try this:

```py
def tags(a):
    tags = []
    for item in a:
       if item.get('data'):
           if all([item["data"]["user_id"]==user_id, item["data"]["project_id"]==project_id]):
            q  =  {"am": item["data"]["activity_message"],"d": item["data"]["activity_created_on"]["$date"] }
            tags.append(q)
    return tags
# print(tags(a))
result = sorted(tags(a), key=lambda x: x['d'], reverse=True)
for i in result:
  print(i["am"])
```

The output will be:

```
Success 2
Success 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sets` do not necessarily preserve order, use a `list` instead:

```
user_id = 1
project_id = 2
a = [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
    },
    "data": {
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "activity_message": "Success 1",
        "activity_created_on": {
            "$date": "2023-02-28T12:30:55.652Z"
        }
    }
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
    },
    "data": {
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "activity_message": "Success 2",
        "activity_created_on": {
            "$date": "2023-02-28T12:36:55.652Z"
        }
    }
}]


def tags(a):
    tags = []  # Set default item!
    for item in a:
        data = item.get('data')
        if data and data["user_id"] == user_id and data[
                "project_id"] == project_id:
            tags.append(data["activity_message"])
    return tags[::-1] # reverse!


print(tags(a))
```

Out:

```
['Success 2', 'Success 1']
```

Answer (score 1):

With this approach the function uses a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`.get()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method and returns a reversed list.

```py
def tags(a):
    return [log["data"]["activity_message"] for log in a
                if log["data"].get("user_id") == user_id and
                log["data"].get("project_id") == project_id][::-1]
    
print(*tags(a), sep="\n")
```

---

```
Success 2
Success 1
```

`print(*tags(a), sep="\n")` unpacks the returned list and prints individual element in a new line.